# Question about Heine-Borel Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I read "Probability and Measure" in page 12. I encountered paragraph [image: here]

Why "the open intervals $(a_k, b_k + \epsilon 2^{-k})$ cover the closed interval $[a + \epsilon, b]$"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $(a_k, b_k] \subseteq (a_k, b_k + \epsilon 2^{-k})$ for all $k$, so $$(a, b] \subseteq \bigcup_{k = 1}^\infty (a_k, b_k] \subseteq \bigcup_{k = 1}^\infty (a_k, b_k + \epsilon 2^{-k})$$

Comment: Is a typo in 2^-n instead 2^-k in ur answer?

Comment: Yes, I meant $(a_k, b_k + \epsilon 2^{-k})$